# Images uploaded to S3 have incorrect encoding

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to download image from GitHub repository and upload it to S3. Uploading works flawlessly but, images served from S3 are corrupted or are encoded in wrong way (they don't render, question mark in frame appears when requesting image), here's code I'm using:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const http = require('axios');
const Bucket = 'png-image-upload-test';
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  params: {
    Bucket
  }
});
const imageUrl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RafalWilinski/rwilinski-page/master/static/linkedin.png';

http.get(imageUrl).then((payload) => {
  s3.putObject({
    Bucket,
    Key: 'image.png',
    Body: payload.data,
    ACL: 'public-read',
    ContentType: 'image/png',
  }, (error, data) => {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    else console.log(data);
  });
})
.catch((error) => { throw new Error(error); });
```

I've tried sending my own `ContentMD5` with `ContentLength` parameters but AWS kept replying that this MD5 is wrong.

I've also tried saving image locally:

```
http.get(imageUrl).then((payload) => fs.writeFile('image.png', payload.data);
```

And then uploading it manually to S3 and it's working perfectly, so I guess something must be with uploading to S3, not downloading from GitHub.

Also, when comparing raw image sources I spotted that these images use totally different encoding.

Image downloaded from GitHub:

```
âPNGIHDR^[P˙VbKGDˇáèÃø  pHYs◊ <more data>
```

Image downloaded from S3:

```
˝PNGIHDR^[P˝VbKGD˝˝˝?   pHYs˝ <more data>
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: The symptoms strongly suggest that the body is being treated as character data, and being subjected to some kind of character set transcoding, when it is of course binary.  For reasons that are not obvious to me, axios has a request configuration attribute `responseType: 'json', // default`.  If my reading of the docs is right (never used axios) this seems problematic.  Other options include `blob`, `stream`, and `arraybuffer`, all of which sound much more binary-friendly, but I am not sufficiently familiar with Node to actually say which one is correct, if this is indeed the problem.

Comment: If sending `Content-MD5` causes S3 to reject an upload, that's a sign that you're doing something to corrupt the data in your code, so that failure was actually a big red flag that corruption was indeed happening prior to the upload, or perhaps by some kind of implicit behavior in the aws-sdk.